# Duplicate Plane on Local Access based upon Rotation Degrees

Tags: python, path

I am semi new to programming python in blender and am trying to take some x,y,z rotation data thats in degree's and duplicate each plane moving it y amount in space so I can visualize the path of the data data captured. Y movement forward is a constant of 4.

[image]

Here is some code that almost gets me to where I think I should be but when duplicating the rotation values i'm trying to set are not coming though and are all 0,0,0.

Idea.

1. Create a plane at 0,0,0 with 90 degree's forward at the Y plane and apply the location, rotation values.
2. Iterate over the rotation data which is in degrees its in Pitch(X), Yaw(Y), Roll(Z) format.
3. Duplicate a plane per data point using the local cords since if you make a copy its not moving forward from the last plane created.  Meaning if plan 3 is at 90degrees and you copy it, it doesn't seem to move forward in local space when creating the next one.
4. A super bonus which I have yet to tackle is to connect each plane with a path so I can move them around similar to a lattice or proportional editing.

```
import bpy
from math import radians

rotation = [
[0.5729577951308232, 0.0, 0.0],
[4.010704565915763, 0.0, 0.5729577951308232], 
[7.448451336700702, 0.0, 1.1459155902616465], 
[11.459155902616466, 0.0, 1.7188733853924696],
[15.469860468532229, 0.0, 2.291831180523293], 
[18.907607239317166, 0.0, 2.8647889756541165],
[22.918311805232932, 0.0, 3.437746770784939], 
[26.35605857601787, 0.0, 4.010704565915763],  
[30.36676314193363, 0.0, 4.583662361046586],  
[34.37746770784939, 0.0, 5.156620156177409],  
[37.81521447863433, 0.0, 5.729577951308233],  
[41.8259190445501, 0.0, 6.302535746439055],   
[45.836623610465864, 0.0, 6.875493541569878], 
[49.2743703812508, 0.0, 7.448451336700702],   
[53.285074947166564, 0.0, 8.021409131831525], 
[57.29577951308232, 0.0, 8.594366926962348],  
[60.73352628386726, 0.0, 9.167324722093172],  
[64.74423084978302, 0.0, 9.740282517223996],
[68.75493541569878, 0.0, 10.313240312354818],
[72.19268218648372, 0.0, 10.886198107485642],
[76.2033867523995, 0.0, 11.459155902616466],
[80.21409131831524, 0.0, 12.032113697747288],
[83.6518380891002, 0.0, 12.60507149287811],
[87.66254265501595, 0.0, 13.178029288008934],
[91.67324722093173, 0.0, 13.750987083139757],
[95.11099399171665, 0.0, 14.32394487827058],
[99.12169855763241, 0.0, 14.896902673401405],
[103.13240312354819, 0.0, 15.469860468532229],
[106.57014989433313, 0.0, 16.04281826366305],
[110.58085446024889, 0.0, 16.615776058793873],
[114.59155902616465, 0.0, 17.188733853924695],
[101.98648753328654, 0.0, 17.76169164905552],
[90.52733163067008, 0.0, 18.334649444186343],
[80.21409131831524, 0.0, 18.907607239317166],
[70.47380880109125, 0.0, 19.48056503444799],
[60.73352628386726, 0.0, 20.053522829578814],
[51.56620156177409, 0.0, 20.626480624709636],
[42.97183463481174, 0.0, 21.199438419840458],
[34.95042550298022, 0.0, 21.772396214971284],
[27.501974166279513, 0.0, 22.345354010102106],
[20.05352282957881, 0.0, 22.918311805232932],
[13.178029288008934, 0.0, 23.491269600363754],
[6.302535746439055, 0.0, 24.064227395494576],
[0.0, 0.0, 24.6371851906254],
[-5.729577951308233, 0.0, 25.21014298575622],
[-10.886198107485642, 0.0, 25.783100780887047],
[-16.615776058793873, 0.0, 26.35605857601787],
[-21.199438419840458, 0.0, 26.929016371148695],
[-25.783100780887047, 0.0, 27.501974166279513],
[-29.79380534680281, 0.0, 28.07493196141034],
[-33.80450991271857, 0.0, 28.64788975654116],
[-37.24225668350351, 0.0, 29.220847551671984],
[-40.680003454288446, 0.0, 29.79380534680281],
[-43.54479242994257, 0.0, 30.36676314193363],
[-46.40958140559668, 0.0, 30.939720937064457],
[-48.70141258611997, 0.0, 31.51267873219528],
[-50.99324376664327, 0.0, 32.0856365273261],
[-52.71211715203574, 0.0, 32.65859432245693],
[-54.4309905374282, 0.0, 33.231552117587746],
[-55.57690612768985, 0.0, 33.80450991271857],
[-56.14986392282068, 0.0, 34.37746770784939],
[-56.7228217179515, 0.0, 34.95042550298022],
[-54.4309905374282, 0.0, 35.52338329811104],
[-52.13915935690491, 0.0, 36.09634109324186],
[-49.84732817638162, 0.0, 36.66929888837269],
[-46.9825392007275, 0.0, 37.24225668350351],
[-44.11775022507339, 0.0, 37.81521447863433],
[-40.680003454288446, 0.0, 38.38817227376516],
[-37.24225668350351, 0.0, 38.96113006889598],
[-33.231552117587746, 0.0, 39.53408786402681],
[-29.220847551671984, 0.0, 40.10704565915763],
[-25.21014298575622, 0.0, 40.680003454288446],
[-20.626480624709636, 0.0, 41.25296124941927],
[-15.469860468532229, 0.0, 41.8259190445501],
[-10.313240312354818, 0.0, 42.398876839680916],
[-4.583662361046586, 0.0, 42.97183463481174],
[1.7188733853924696, 0.0, 43.54479242994257],
[8.594366926962348, 0.0, 44.11775022507339],
[16.04281826366305, 0.0, 44.69070802020421],
[23.49126960036375, 0.0, 45.26366581533504],
[32.0856365273261, 0.0, 45.836623610465864],
[41.8259190445501, 0.0, 46.40958140559668],
[52.13915935690491, 0.0, 46.98253920072751],
[63.598315259521385, 0.0, 47.555496995858334],
[77.34930234266115, 0.0, 48.12845479098915],
[92.81916281119337, 0.0, 48.70141258611997],
[114.01860123103383, 0.0, 49.2743703812508],
[105.42423430407148, 0.0, 49.84732817638162],
[97.40282517223994, 0.0, 50.42028597151244],
[89.38141604040842, 0.0, 50.99324376664327],
[81.36000690857689, 0.0, 51.56620156177409],
[73.33859777674537, 0.0, 52.13915935690491],
[65.31718864491384, 0.0, 52.71211715203574],
[56.7228217179515, 0.0, 53.285074947166564],
[48.70141258611997, 0.0, 53.85803274229739],
[40.680003454288446, 0.0, 54.43099053742821],
[32.65859432245692, 0.0, 55.00394833255903],
[24.064227395494576, 0.0, 55.57690612768985],
[16.04281826366305, 0.0, 56.14986392282068],
[8.021409131831525, 0.0, 56.7228217179515],

]

size = 2

#set default plane at start, TODO: read initial start point of frame (0)
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size = size, align='WORLD', location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

#slected object
so = bpy.context.active_object

#set degrees going on y axis to mimic moving forward in Z, since Z is down in blender
degrees = 90
so.rotation_euler[0] += radians(degrees)

#select active object and apply transforms
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = so
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)

#add more planes by spacing, translate and apply transform
for x in rotation: 
   
    spacing = 4
   
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = so
    #print(so.location)
    #so.select_set(True)
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked = False, mode ='TRANSLATION')
    #Rotation between cords XYZ Pitch, Yaw and Roll
    # rotation x
    so.rotation_euler[0] = radians(x[0])
    #rotation y
    so.rotation_euler[1] = radians(x[2])
    #rotation z
    so.rotation_euler[2] = radians(x[1])

    # push forward in Y
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, spacing ,0), orient_type="LOCAL")
```

I may be improperly making a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Add and duplicate operators leave the object active, so you don't need to set it as active one more time after the operations. You also need to rotate the duplicated object, so whatever object that is left as active after duplicate:

```
import bpy
from math import radians

rotation = [
[0.5729577951308232, 0.0, 0.0],
[4.010704565915763, 0.0, 0.5729577951308232], 
[7.448451336700702, 0.0, 1.1459155902616465], 
[11.459155902616466, 0.0, 1.7188733853924696],
[15.469860468532229, 0.0, 2.291831180523293], 
[18.907607239317166, 0.0, 2.8647889756541165],
[22.918311805232932, 0.0, 3.437746770784939], 
# ... 
] 

rotation = [[radians(values) for values in lists] for lists in rotation]

size = 2
rot = (radians(90),0,0) 
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add(size = size, align='WORLD', location=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), rotation=rot)
bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=True, rotation=True, scale=True)

spacing = 4
for x in rotation: 
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate(linked = False, mode ='TRANSLATION')
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler = x
    bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(0, spacing ,0), orient_type="LOCAL")
```

I don't know what you are doing but for procedural geometry creation, you should probably look into geometry nodes. Might be easier to get the result you want.

Comment: Wow.. thank you.. this is for a project that takes AI animation keyframes that are in a format  rotation_3d_z = "0:(0),100:(1),400:(1),450:(0)" that needs to then be converted to to radians and degrees.  The idea is to create a visual representation of how the animation path looks in 3D.. ideally i would attach a camera and fly though each square to see how my set of keyframes looks..  Thanks for the help.. now I need to connect each plane with a path so I can add the camera.. cheers!!